# Is there any way to automate sending a CSV file from a root directory to a google drive?

Tags: csv, google-sheets

kind of a unique situation here that i seem to be running out of options for. There is a daily upload that gets put into a root directory folder. All I'm looking for is a way to automatically upload that new information in that file to a google drive. Simple but unfortunately this is company data so certain add-ons, scripts, programs can't be used.

Here's similar solutions that i found throughout this site and the web that seem to be unusable due job imposed limitations

1.sync root folder to google drive (**company only allows C/ drive folders to get synced**)

2.use gspread in python to connect google data (**company uses python but won't allow gspread to be installed**)

3.upload csv files to public accessible site to allow connection to google (**nope, its confidential data**)

4.change the file format or upload location (**the data extraction is only able to be sent in csv form in that specific root folder**)

i'm not necessarily looking for anyone to write a script but just want to see if there are any other paths that i should try that i may have missed.

Comment: From `this is company data so certain add-ons, scripts, programs can't be used.`, in your situation, you want to achieve your goal without using a script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I don't mind using a script at all. I think the problem I keep running into is every script i've found uses some add-on that i'm unable to use. Is there a method you'd recommend? Again, not looking for someone to do the entire script, just a little direction if possible

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that your goal had included using a script. In this case, in order to upload a file to Google Drive, it is required to use the access token. In your situation, can you retrieve and use the access token to upload a file to Google Drive? I thought that it is required to confirm whether you can retrieve and use the access token for uploading a file.